# Explanation for a Math notation in Economics

Tags: probability, notation, economics

I don't understand the following match equation for A (number 2), especially the subscripts. This is within the context of a Bayesian game (which is fine if you don't know, but I thought it might help explain for some of you who know economics). Thanks a lot!

I pasted the entire definiton for Bayesian so you can understand the context.

[image]

Comment: You can ask this here, but I reckon you'll get better answers if you ask this on economics.stackexchange , as they will be more familiar with economics notation. This isn't standard maths notation.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I have updated my question for the entire definition. Let me know if this is of any help.

Comment: Oh, perhaps they mean the Cartesian product.  So that an element of $A$ is a choice of an action for each player.  That seems clearly the intent behind the definition of $T$.

Comment: But why not include a link to the actual reference?

Comment: @lulu would you mind clarifying you previous explanation? Also, it's a pdf, not a link unfortunately.

Comment: If you have two sets, $X,Y$, their Cartesian product is the set of pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.  You can generalize this to any collection of sets.  I didn't think this was likely for the notion of "action" (as, typically, the actions of one player rule out/compel actions of the others).  But I don't know what they intend to do with $A$, and, as I mentioned, it makes more intuitive sense for $T$.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) is wikipedia on the notion of a Cartesian Product.

Comment: You have $N$ *players* each with its own set $A_i$ of *actions*. The set $A$ of all action profiles is the cartesian product (see comment above) and it is the set of all $N$-uple $(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_N)$ where each $a_i$ is one action for the $i$-th player: $a_i \in A_i$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks, I'll check it out. Also, people seem much chiller here than SO.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is the cartesian product of $n$ players' simultaneous "actions", that is, $a\in A$ is an $n$-tuple containing the *action* ("pure action profile") of each player. Similarly $t\in T$ is an $n$-tuple containing the type of player each player is. Each ordered-set of player-types has a probability $\pi(t)$ of occurring.

$$u_{i_k}:\left((a_{i_1},a_{i_2},\cdots,a_{i_n}),(t_{i_1},t_{i_2},\cdots,t_{i_n})\right)\mapsto y_{i_k}$$

where $y_{i_k}=u_{i_k}(a,t)$ is the payoff received by player $i_k$ from that situation.

Everywhere they wrote $i$ without subscript they could've written $i_k$ for clarity's sake